# Spring Cloud - Registry Service port customization

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I'd like to customize the Eureka port with Spring Cloud.
With the default port below, the services registry sees itself right (within the provided GUI)

```
spring:
  application:
    name: services-registry
server:
  port: 8761

eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
    nonSecurePort: ${server.port}
  client:
    register-with-eureka: true
    fetch-registry: false
    service-url:
      default-zone: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/
```

But if I just change server.port to 8787, no service can register itself, not even the services registry itself.

```
2017-01-09 16:18:21.584  WARN 17496 --- [nfoReplicator-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient    : Request execution failure
2017-01-09 16:18:21.584  WARN 17496 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_SERVICES-REGISTRY/xxx.org:services-registry:8787 - registration failed Cannot execute request on any known server

com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
...
2017-01-09 16:13:33.299  WARN 17496 --- [nfoReplicator-0] c.n.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator     : There was a problem with the instance info replicator

com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
```

Can someone explain this issue and save my day? Thanks!

Comment: What is the error in the log?

Comment: console traces added above

Comment: do the errors persist or is it one time? There is a chicken and egg scenario here.

Comment: as far as I can see it, the error is permanent. Even when there is neither "instance" conf, nor "service-url" conf

Comment: What do you mean "no service can register itself, not even the services registry itself."

Comment: I mean that the services list is empty in the monitoring GUI (URL localhost:8761/). If I set the port to 8761, the registry is listed, but the registering fails when the port is 8787 (URL localhost:8787/) see provided traces

Comment: Is it relevant for a Eureka server to register with itself?

Comment: Not it is not, smarty. Why do you ask ? I needed a PoC, this is training. Do you have a pb with that ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ok, got it... the label after service-url property (which can be aliased as serviceUrl in YML) is a HashMap **KEY**, not a property label. So it has to be kept as a Camel Case tag in any ways!

```
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://[myIP@]:8787/eureka
```

Comment: Oh my God! You are a true life saver man! I spent two days to find it!!!!

Comment: How can we find the IP address

Comment: 2024 year... this issue still present )) Thank you for answer!